# How do animals that live in dens keep the dens from flooding?

Tags: zoology, ethology, environment

When it rains heavily or flooding starts what do animals like foxes,wolves, and any other animal that makes a den or lives underground do.? Do their den's/home's flood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this depends a lot on the animal but generally the shape or location of the den. Simply don't build dens in places prone to flooding, otherwise the shape of the den works.

Foxes for instance which do build dens is places were flooding can occur build V shaped tunnels to their natal dens, so water would have to run uphill to reach the places they actually use. Beavers likewise dig there dens upwards.

here is picture from something completely unrelated that can help.
[image]

https://www.jstor.org/stable/41713116